# What was Hagrid's boggart form?

Tags: harry-potter, hagrid

Hagrid doesn't seem to be afraid of any animals or people. But in some sense he is timid.

**Is there any indication what Hagrid's boggart form is?**

Comment: Welcome to the SciFi/Fantasy Stack Exchange! I have edited your question to remove the request for speculation, as we generally don't allow speculative/opinionated questions on this site. Please let me know if you have any issues with my changes.

Answer (score 10):

### Main canon

Within the main canon, we **simply don't know.**

**Guesswork:** Like Harry, he certainly isn't fond of Dementors and a very common boggart form among his contemporaries is Lord Voldemort. He also has several friends (Dumbledore, notably) and a close relative (Grawp) that he wouldn't want to see their corpses.

---

### Lower-canon speculation.

The [Official Harry Potter Bloomsbury Website](http://www.harrypotter.bloomsbury.com/uk/fun-stuff/who-is-your-hogwarts-best-friend/#hpq-top) contains a quiz about "your Hogwarts best friend" in which we learn the main fears of various characters, including Hagrid.

Assuming these fears also represent the person's boggart form, Hagrid's would be **Azkaban Prison.**

[image]

Comment: That actually raises a possibly interesting incidental question that I never thought about before: what are the limitations to a boggart? It can clearly become just about any person or creature (dead or alive), or an inanimate object like the Moon… but would it be able to turn itself into something like an entire prison? To scale? Engulfing you, somehow? The mind boggarts. (Sorry…)

Comment: I just did that test you link to, and ended up with Hagrid as my result. I think that's a good thing...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I would imagine prison would be represented by the dementors that guard the cells, or possibly one of the deranged inmates (not sure if there was ever mention of a prisoner giving Hagrid any trouble).